# Ruby-rspec how can I include a file that is a "common" before (:all) block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```
describe Line do

  before :all do
    puts "In #{self.class.description}"
  end
  ...
```

which works fine.

I would like that code (just the three lines) to be in a helper file (called header.rb) but when I try that with:

```
load "header.rb"
```

I get:

```
undefined method `before' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried `require_relative` and got the same result.

Comment: why are you doing this? if you only need to know the class you are testing just run rspec with -fs option: ´rspec -fs ./spec/´ . Read the man for the -f (--format) option, you can use your own formatters

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** If this applys to all your tests, you can set it in configure

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do
    puts "In #{self.class.description}"
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    puts "More stuff can be added in chain"
  end
end
```

**Option 2:** If you only want to use it in some tests and the context would be a bit more complex, you can use `shared_context`

```
# spec/support/some_shared_context.rb
shared_context "putting class" do
  before :all do
    puts "In #{self.class.description}"
  end
end

# Test file
require 'spec/support/some_shared_context.rb'

describe "test foo" do
  include_context "putting class"

  # normal test code
end
```

More about shared_context: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context